# removed paths from group removes live paint effect as well Ai CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, cs6, fill

I removed a piece of the art work from the group however when I cut and pasted it outside of the group it looked like this.

[image] I used live paint on the group so I am guessing it has something to do with it in that live paint from what I understand is like an effect and now its been cut out therefore the effect no longer applies.

Comment: Seems to me that you really ought to stay away from live paint for this project. Theres nothing to be gained as itseasy enough to properly fill the area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must** `Expand` the Live Paint group if you want to make **any** changes 
other than merely filling an area with color.

A Live Paint group is **strictly** click-to-fill, *nothing more*. 
Not delete, not move, not alter, *nothing*. Only click-to-fill.

You've posted several questions... they **all** seem to directly relate to this very aspect.

It may be helpful to review [Adobe's Help files regarding Live Paint](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/live-paint-groups.html).